# jQuery - How to fade out sticky button on scroll

Tags: jquery

I have this button with CSS class `.comment-link`.
The button is located at the top of the comment section on my wordpress site.
I've made the button sticky when it enters the viewport.

I'd like it to fade out to a given transparency when the user scrolls up or down.
When scrolling stops, the button fades in again.

I've tried and searched but can't get it to work.

**CSS:**

```
.comment-link {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 20px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -57px 0 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Found this script but can't figure out how to implement the fade-in and fade-out at the callback function.

```
// Setup isScrolling variable
var isScrolling;

// Listen for scroll events
window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {

    // Clear our timeout throughout the scroll
    window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );

    // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
    isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {

        // Run the callback
        console.log( 'Scrolling has stopped.' );

    }, 66);

}, false);
```

Comment: are you looking for this?, where they clear the timeout you can add the fadeout and fadein inside the timeout https://gomakethings.com/detecting-when-a-visitor-has-stopped-scrolling-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: Thanks Ramon. I looked at the jQuery fade function but i am a complete newbie to javascript and have no clue how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the code with the fadein/fadeout added, change the opacity to any value you want and that should work just fine.(to make the button more fade rather then change opacity instant, add `transition: 0.3s all ease` in the css of the button(`comment-link`))

```js
var isScrolling;

// Listen for scroll events
window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {
    window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );
    let button = $('.comment-link');
  $(button).css('opacity', '0.3');
    isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
    $(button).css('opacity', '1');
    }, 500);

}, false);
```

```css
.comment-link {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 20px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -57px 0 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
}
.space{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="space">

</div>
<button class="comment-link">

</button>
<div class="space">

</div>
```